# Why is my Windows desktop "staggering"?

Tags: windows, windows-10, freeze

Where I work, desktop PCs are forcibly upgraded remotely -- and rebooted after that.

After one such upgrade/reboot last week I found my machine almost unusable as the entire desktop would freeze -- for a few seconds -- *once or twice per minute*.

You could bring up the clock applet and see the seconds stop updating for anywhere from 1 to 15 seconds. This happens right away after reboot -- even while I'm logging-in: input is ignored, and any key pressed will remain "pressed" for the duration of the seizure.

The problem is the same whether I connect to it via Remote Desktop or login directly -- so it is not the video-card. Also, I noticed, that any music playing continues uninterrupted -- if I watch a YouTube video, for example, the video will stop updating, but the sound continues.

The desktop support are at their wits' end, talking about replacing my computer altogether. They claim, no one else has reported such a problem. Maybe, someone can suggest something less invasive than that?

The machine is reasonably new and does not *crash* -- only *freezes* as described -- which makes me doubt, the hardware is responsible... There is no obvious activity reported by the Task Manager, when a seizure occurs.

Comment: did you try to do a system restore? Also try to enter safe mode and uninstall the latest update then probably block it temporarily

Comment: I don't have the permissions necessary to do that myself, and the Desktop people wouldn't roll back "security". Also, the machine's been patched again once or twice since then...

Comment: @MikhailT. - Contact your system Administrator, any solution to this problem, requires Administrator access which you don’t have.